# Why SQLite is not running on NetBeans IDE integrated with java on linux?

Tags: java, linux, sqlite, netbeans

First of all my operating system is Ubuntu 14.04 , and I use NetBeans IDE 8.0.1 for java programing. I want to build a simple application to access a database file and because I need a serverless driver I downloaded sqlite-JDBC-3.8.7.jar and added it to the Libraries folder in my project as a new Library. After that I get a simple code to test the driver which is:

```
 import java.sql.*;

    public class test
    {
      public static void main( String args[] )
      {
        Connection c = null;
        try {
          Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
          c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
          System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
          System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
      }
    }
```

which must create a new database called test.db and print "Opened database successfully"
but an error occurred and the exception message was :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.sqlite.core.NativeDB._open(Ljava/lang/String;I)V
    at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB._open(Native Method)
    at org.sqlite.core.DB.open(DB.java:161)
    at org.sqlite.core.CoreConnection.open(CoreConnection.java:145)
    at org.sqlite.core.CoreConnection.<init>(CoreConnection.java:66)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Connection.<init>(JDBC3Connection.java:21)
    at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:23)
    at org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.<init>(SQLiteConnection.java:45)
    at org.sqlite.JDBC.createConnection(JDBC.java:114)
    at org.sqlite.JDBC.connect(JDBC.java:88)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:233)
    at foodchooser.test.main(test.java:13)
Java Result: 1
```

And the problem is not only in this test code but wherever i use :

```
 Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
  c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:--WhateverPath--");
```

In other word i am not able to use sqlite.
PLZ HELP!! and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there are some compatibility issues with the newest SQLite-JDBC library not playing well with `Linux`. The older versions don't seem to have this problem.

Deleted the other SQLite-JDBC libraries and included only the oldest named "sqlite-jdbc-3.7.15-SNAPSHOT.jar" from [this](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/downloads) url